# Selenium continue script even if element is not present

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is an example of what my code currently looks like,

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "FirstName").send_keys("MyFirstName")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "LastName").send_keys("MyLastName")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "PhoneNumber").send_keys("myPhoneNumber")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Email").send_keys("myEmail")
```

When for instance element ID "PhoneNumber" isn't present, the script will stop with the error code "Unable to locate element", what needs to be added or changed in order to continue the script without abruption even if a certain element is not present?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `try`/`except` block

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

...
driver.find_element(By.ID, "LastName").send_keys("MyLastName")
try:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "PhoneNumber").send_keys("myPhoneNumber")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No Phone number input field found")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Email").send_keys("myEmail")
...
```

or use conditional operator as below:

```
if driver.find_elements(By.ID, "PhoneNumber"):
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "PhoneNumber").send_keys("myPhoneNumber")
```

Comment: One question, is it crucial to have a statement after the "except NoSuchElementException:"? would removing the print statement still work?

Comment: @user901 you can use any action instead of just printing message

Comment: What action should I write to have it continue without printing any message?

Comment: @user901 , you can simply use `except NoSuchElementException: pass` if you don't want to execute real action

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a try statements, it would look like this:

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "FirstName").send_keys("MyFirstName")
except:
    print("Element not found")

try:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "LastName").send_keys("MyLastName")
except:
    print("Element not found")

try:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "PhoneNumber").send_keys("myPhoneNumber")
except:
    print("Element not found")

try:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "Email").send_keys("myEmail")
except:
    print("Element not found")
```

It should print out "Element not found" and then continue the script